# A formula for the degree of a algebraic number field.

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Let $K$ be an algebraic number field with $[K:\mathbb{Q}] =n$ and $R$ its ring of integers. Let $p \in \mathbb{P}$ be a prime number and $pR = P_1^{e_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot P_g^{e_g}$ with pariwise distinct $P_1,\ldots ,P_g \in \max(R)$, i.e. the $P_i$ is a maximal ideals in $R$.
>
> Show that $\sum_{i=1}^g e_if_i = n$ for $f_i := [R/P_i : \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}]$ for all $i \in \{1,\ldots, g\}$.

I do not know how to do this. The exercise came after learning about the ideal norm and establishing that it is multiplicative. So I suppose that it is connected to that, but I do not see how.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2477672/sum-of-ramification-indices-times-residue-degrees-equals-degree-of-extension). A proof can be found in books on algebraic number theory.

Comment: You say it's connected to the multiplicativity of the ideal norm, and you have a factorization of an ideal right there in the exercise. So apply multiplicativity to it! You get $N(p) = \prod N(P_i)^{e_i}$. Now can you compute these norms? For starters, can you compute that $N(p) = p^n$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I know that there is exactly one prime number $p$ with $p \in P$ for each $p \in \max(R)$, and that $N(P)  = p^k$ for some integer $k$, but I do not see how this is related to $\sum_{i=1}^g e_if_i$.

Comment: Here's another hint: the identity you want to prove is equivalent to $p^n = \prod_{i=1}^g p^{e_i f_i}$. Does this seem like it might have something to do with the norms of the ideals now?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks for your patience, now I understand your reasoning. But I still have one question: Why do we know that for $p$ holds $p \in P_i$ for ALL i ? I know that there has to be precisely one prime in every maximal ideal, but why is it always the same here? I suppose it is because $pR$ is the set of all $p$ multiples of $R$, but I do not see why.

Comment: By definition, each $P_i$ is a factor of $(p)$, which means each $P_i$ must contain $(p)$. Just observe that the ideal product $IJ$ is contained in $I$ (and also in $J$); we always have $IJ \subseteq I \cap J$ (and for coprime ideals this is an equality).